# Jquery Animate submenu but close other opens at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an horizontal menu with multiple submenues. If you have toggled one submenu and try to open another, the first one will close while the other one opens.

I have managed to make this, but they do not open/close at the same time. Instead it opens the new one first - then close the other one.

You can look at the full code here: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zjtu5jj/)

Relevant html:

```
<li> <a href="#" class="has-dropdown"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i> Dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Relevant css:

```
.sidebar-nav li ul {
    max-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.sidebar-nav li ul.show {
    max-height: 1000px;
    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

Relevant JS:

```
$(".sidebar-nav .has-dropdown").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dropdown = $(this).parent().find(".dropdown");

    if (!$(dropdown).hasClass("show")) {
        $(".dropdown").removeClass("show");
        $(dropdown).addClass("show");
    } else $(".dropdown").removeClass("show");

});
```

Comment: This is because of the delay caused by setting your `max-height` property to such a high value for this animation. You should try setting it to a lower value (the maximum height the submenus will ever achieve)


[here's a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zjtu5jj/6/)

Comment: Thanks! Changed it to a lower number and now it works perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property that you are animating is `max-height`. But you are defining `max-height: 1000px` when your dropdown only have `250px`. You need to define an exact `max-height` or as lower as possible, like:

```
.sidebar-nav li ul.show {
    max-height: 250px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/7zjtu5jj/5/)